# Can we use ChromeDriver driver= new ChromeDriver(); Over WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();?

Tags: selenium

Why we always write:

**WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();**

But Not the Below:

**ChromeDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();**

Comment: Where do you get the exception?

Comment: In what line exactly?

Comment: There are no lines numbers in the code you posted... you need to tell what line is it by the code.

Comment: You don't have property `"Browser"`. Check the spelling and letters case in properties file.

Comment: The only thing that can be `null` in the line `if (browserName.equals("Chrome"))` is `browserName`, which means `prop.getProperty("Browser");` returned `null`, which means it couldn't find the property `Browser` in the properties file.

Comment: Are you sure the line is `if (browserName.equals("Chrome"))`? you wrote `chrome` in the properties file but compare to `Chrome`. The `driver` will not be initialized and you will get `NullPointerException` at `driver.manage().window().maximize();`.

Comment: If `prop.load(ip);` wasn't performed it could explain it. Debug this part and try to load the file using absolute path (`C:\..`) just to check.

Answer (score 0):

Webdriver instance is not passed to the sub classes extending the super class. Create a constructor in Super class and Pass the webdriver instance.